# How to read such a file into R?

Tags: r

I have a file which contains data format like this:

```
           48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70
A_row  17 16 10 12  9 15 10 19  9 15  7  3  5 12  6  4  6  8  1  7  6  5  4
B_row  3  5  1  5  2  0  3  1  2  2  3  1  3  2  1  2  1  1  1  0  0  1  1
           71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 80 81 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 94 97 103 104
A_row  1 6 0 2  9 5 1 19 9 15 7  3  5 12  6  4  6  8  1  7  6  5  4
B_row  2 5 1 5  2 0 3 1  2 2  3  1  3  2  1  2  1  1  1  0  0  1  1
```

Is there anyway to read this format into R? Thanks! :>

Comment: Why not `read.table()`?

Comment: If your data is truly representative (i.e., unequal number of data on each group of rows), then you'll likely need to roll your own function, perhaps using `readLines`, `grep`, and `strsplit`. If it's structured better than you have, then perhaps `read.delim` or `read.fwf` are viable alternatives.

Comment: What is your desired output? Because of the row-oriented and variable-length rows, it isn't immediately obvious what you want from this. Perhaps edit your question to include a small section of the desired output. (For instance: a matrix with this data transposed, three columns, first row 48, 17, 3.)

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for your reply. I just need to load the file in the script.

Comment: The question, @Ben, is "what data structure are you looking for?". Because it is irregular, a standard matrix import (and data.frame) will include `NA`s, perhaps not what you want. List of vectors? List of lists? Are the column headers meaningful? Convert into a data.frame with three columns, *as I suggested in my previous comment*? What tool will be using this data? (You need to learn how to [ask better questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).)

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)

text = 
  "48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70
A_row  17 16 10 12  9 15 10 19  9 15  7  3  5 12  6  4  6  8  1  7  6  5  4
B_row  3  5  1  5  2  0  3  1  2  2  3  1  3  2  1  2  1  1  1  0  0  1  1
71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 80 81 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 94 97 103 104
A_row  1 6 0 2  9 5 1 19 9 15 7  3  5 12  6  4  6  8  1  7  6  5  4
B_row  2 5 1 5  2 0 3 1  2 2  3  1  3  2  1  2  1  1  1  0  0  1  1"

df  = 
  text %>% 
  # split over newlines (could also be accomplished by readLines)
  stri_split_fixed(pattern = "\n") %>% 
  # need to take first list corresponding to text
  extract2(1) %>%
  # make the text a column in the dataframe
  {data_frame(values = .)} %>%
  # identify rows based on what type of data they contain
  # assume a repeating pattern every 3 lines
  mutate(variable = c("id", "A_row", "B_row") %>% rep(length.out = n())) %>%
  # for each type of data
  group_by(variable) %>%
  summarize(value = 
              values %>%
              # concatenate all values
              paste(collapse = " ") %>%
              # remove headers (might need to modify regex)
              stri_replace_all_regex("[A-Z]_row  ", "") %>%
              # split as space separated data
              stri_split_regex(pattern = " +")) %>%
  # unnest the lists
  unnest(value) %>%
  # make values numeric
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value)) %>%
  # for each variable, number 1 through n() to guess new row ID's
  group_by(variable) %>%
  mutate(n = 1:n()) %>%
  # reshape data
  spread(variable, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, one approach would be to use [`read.delim`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/read.table) (maybe in chunks using skip & nrows), and then [`cbind`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/cbind) to reassemble them.

Depending on the file (as pasted it looks like it might need additional preprocessing to be used with read.delim), another approach would be to use [`readLines`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/readLines) and [`strsplit`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/strsplit)